# How to handle and play a skeletal animation in three.js in its last version

Tags: three.js, skinning, skeletal-animation

I know there is the [skinning_blending](http://localhost/mrdoob-three.js-r71/#webgl_animation_skinning_blending) model but as it has the gui control (the dat.gui as for all other threejs examples) so the code became too complexe and i couldn't get the simple way like which i found for a previous older threejs version like this one :

```
                var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
                loader.load('../assets/models/simpleManMesh2.json', function (model, mat) {

                   var mat = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xF0C8C9, skinning: true});
                    mesh = new THREE.SkinnedMesh(model, mat);


                    // register the animation
                   THREE.AnimationHandler.add(model.animation);

                   var animation = new THREE.Animation(mesh, "saluuut");

                    scene.add(mesh);

                    // start the animation
                    animation.play();

                }, '../assets/models');
```

for which and same as many other people i got the error :

> THREE.AnimationHandler.add() has been deprecated.

So what i ask for is a same simple code (without any gui control) but which works in the lastest version. Best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just now is `THREE.Animation()` :

```
loader.load('yourfile.json',function(geometry,materials){
    for(var i in materials)materials[i].skinning=true;

    mesh=new THREE.SkinnedMesh(
        geometry,
        new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials)
    );
    scene.add(mesh);

    animation=new THREE.Animation(mesh,geometry.animations[0]);

    animation.play();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but the animation doesn't play, only the mesh was displayed and no errors are mentioned. Here are my files http://pastebin.com/7iNTjN4K and http://pastebin.com/nhfCTETm

Comment: because in your `render` function you have `if(animmesh)THREE.AnimationHandler.update(clock.getDelta);`, in the code above you pasted you need to change `mesh` to `animmesh` so the animation updates.